# Perform a while loop for a certain time in Ruby

Tags: ruby, timer, while-loop

I want to perform a loop for `10` minutes. But I do not want to use sleep. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
starttime = Time.now
while Time.now < starttime + 10*60
   # ...
end
```